# WCF Callback is not being executed. Timeout issue?

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, timeout

So I have a client server working with netNamedPipes with WCF on C#.

When I set the callbacks to be `OneWay = true`, they work, but if I try to make the callback to return a value, they stop working the value is not returned to the server, but the client callback function is called.

Error:

`SOURCE:
 mscorlib
TARGET:
 Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
MESSAGE:
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Why is this happening? Can be some timeout issue? How can I make this timeout timer bigger on code?(no config file).

Thank you

EDIT: 
What I do is:
My client calls the server, I server method called saves the callback channel and when I need to do the callback (out of that method/function, in other function that does not deppend on that one) I do the callback.

Comment: This doesn't look like a timeout. Please check if the `CallContext`is set properly.

Comment: callbacks = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallbackContract>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
Before the callback, I had a value set to false which was killing the thread and closing the host so the callback was unable to be done.